# Lazarus resource - Using a resource leads to an error in linking

Tags: resources, embedded-resource, lazarus

I searched around but found not any solution, so I try here:

I want to integrate images (I did it with delphi before in this way) that are used by my program and load them at runtime.

My idea  was to
1.) create a resource file with

```
lazres <resourcename> <imagename>
```

2.) include the resource file in the source

```
{$R <resourcename>}
```

3.) compile
Result:

```
Unable to find file "Debug: Trying to open file /medi/media/work/src.hg/ylazlib/test/test.src/libtest6.lpr".
```

The filename above is the project source and should be found.
I found out that this error almost alwas results from invalid resource files.
But the message should be explaining the problem in a better manner.

If I rename the resource file  ( so it can not be found by linker) I get a 'correct' error message. In this case the unit that requires the resource is opened and the message states that the resource file  can not be opened.

So what am I doing wrong here? 
(I also tried to insert images in different format to the resource - so the image itself may not the problem)
any help apreciated - Thanks in advance
Note: OS: debian sid [fpc 2.6.4] Lazarus SVN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure to follow is a bit different than in Delphi. As [**explained here**](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Resources), you have to

- add `LResources` to the uses clause.
- include the res file produced by Lazres in the initialization section.
- uses `{$I myRes}` rather than `{$R myRes}`.

a quick test with

console lzares cmd:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\temp>lazres res.res project1.lpr=blah
```

source code:
    unit Unit1;

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,LResources;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.lfm}

initialization
{$I res.res}

end.
```

compiles and runs fine. Then later this can be a bit tricky to load the res if they are raw data but for pictures it's quite straightforward, cf the example in the previous link.

Comment: LResources is already added as well to the unit as to the project...
Well I found out that there is something that bugged me:
I issued 
lazres <resourcename> <imagename>
where I didn't specify the extension of resource-name
You get completely different results when specifying an extension for the targetfilename.
Thanks for your help - I think I got that now.